# $_POST data is empty after submit

Tags: php, html, post

I'm having a contact form by html below:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="http://voicemarketing.cmctelecom.vn/php/contact-form.php" method="POST">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Your Name *</label>
            <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Your Company Name *</label>
            <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your company name." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="companyname" id="companyname" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Your phone number *</label>
            <input type="number" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your phone number." maxlength="12" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Your email address *</label>
            <input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Message *</label>
            <textarea maxlength="5000" data-msg-required="Please enter your message." rows="10" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-xlg" data-loading-text="Loading...">
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to get the value by $_POST

```
$fields = array(
0 => array(
    'text' => 'Name',
    'val' => $_POST['name']
),
1 => array(
    'text' => 'Email address',
    'val' => $_POST['email']

),
2 => array(
    'text' => 'Message',
    'val' => $_POST['message']

),
3 => array(
    'text' => 'Company',
    'val' => $_POST['companyname']
),
4 => array(
    'text' => 'Phone Number',
    'val' => $_POST['phonenumber']
));
```

Like usual, I put $_POST['name of form']
but only name, email, message are working
and companyname, phonenumber return nothing.
I really can't figure what is the problem is

Comment: You want to get the value form `array`

Comment: Did you print `$_REQUEST[]` ?

Comment: Before `$fields = array( ...)` declare variable as array  `$fields = array()`

Comment: @RameshS you don't need to do that. Ann Ann, your example code works for me no worries - you may need to supply some more information to help debug it.

Comment: I tried to:
`foreach($fields as $field) {
 $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
}
`

the message was:

`Name: 213123

Email address: 123123@s

Message: sadasdasd

Company: 

Phone Number: `

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` to see exactly what key/values are being submitted from the form.

Comment: Your code is working fine at my place. i am getting {"response":"success"}.

Comment: You said that `I put $_POST['name of form']`. What is 'name of form'?
Try to get value from `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: `array(3) { ["name"]=> string(6) "123123" ["email"]=> string(12) "123123@g.com" ["message"]=> string(10) "sâdasdasd" } {"response":"success"}` I did like above for 5 but only 3 of them is showed by `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database is set up correctly, sometimes you might be trying to put text inside of a "int" type row, which will result in this kind of issue. Worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your POST variable first on top and make sure that the name attribute is same with the POST VARIABLES.

Answer (score 0):

Close the  in the html part of the code and set the type of phone number to text.

```
<form>.....</form>
```

Comment: I missed that line on the question but I closed it properly, I tried to changed it to text but no hope
that's really weird